# Smaato requires location capability for Windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, smaato

I integrated Smaato in my Windows phone 8 app and it seems that it requires the location capability, something that I don't want to add to my app. Is there a way to avoid adding the capability and still use Smaato?

/thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 versions of the Windows Phone 8 SDK for Smaato. One requires/uses location and one doesn't.

You'll find the one which doesn't need the location capability at https://downloads.smaato.com/windows/Smaato%20SDK%20for%20WP8%20-%20V1.5.0.6%20no%20location.zip